# Transferring wallet.dat from PC to Raspberry PI

Tags: wallet.dat, backup, raspberry-pi

I have the Stratis QT sofware running on my computer. I also have a working version of stratisd running on a raspberry pi, which I set up following this [tutorial](https://www.gitbook.com/book/olcko/staking-stratis-on-a-raspberry-pi/details)

If I try to swap my wallet.dat on my Raspberry PI for the wallet.dat I have on my PC, the program wont start. It doesn't give any error messages either. Swapping back to the old wallet.dat doesn't help either. I have to delete everything and re-compile it.

Is it even possible to access a wallet from the different devices?